# group in months in a view

Tags: python, odoo

How can I group the view of an account by months and that within months are the accounts that I created. For example: In the month of August there is the account called bank and cash and the same with the month of September that has the cash and bank account since these accounts have had movement in those months.

link of the example to what I want to reach and how it is currently: [enter link description here](https://ibb.co/PCzj4ZQ)

table view code:

```
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="proyecto_rc.tree_account_list">  
    <field name="name">list de account</field>
    <field name="model">proyecto_rc.account</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree>
          <field name="id"/>
          <field name="title"/>
          <field name="tipo_account"/>
       </tree>
    </field>
    </record>

    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="proyecto_rc.account_form">
            <field name="name">proyecto_rc</field>
            <field name="model">proyecto_rc.account</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Accounts">
                    <sheet>
                        <group col="4">
                        <separator string="Registro de cuentas" colspan="4"/>
                            <field name="id"/>
                            <field name="title"/>
                            <field name="tipo_account"/>
                            <field name="total_account_debit"/>
                            <field name="total_account_credit"/>

                        </group>
                        <group>
                        <separator string="Document" colspan="4"/>
                        <field name="detail_document_ids" nolabel="1">
                        <tree string="Asiento" editable="false">
                            <field name="date"/>
                        </tree>
                        </field>
                        </group>
                    </sheet>
                </form>
            </field>
    </record>

    <!-- actions opening views on models -->
    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="proyecto_rc.account_action_window">
    <field name="name">Registro de cuenta</field>    
    <field name="res_model">proyecto_rc.account</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    </record>

    <!-- server action to the one above -->

    <record model="ir.actions.server" id="proyecto_rc.account_action_server">
    <field name="name"> cuenta server</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_proyecto_rc_account"/>
    <field name="state">code</field>
    <field name="code">
        action = {
        "type": "ir.actions.act_window",
        "view_mode": "tree,form",
        "res_model": self._name,
        }
    </field>
    </record>
```

Comment: So you want to group movements not accounts? you want to show accounts that had movements on that month?

Comment: is that each account is in many movements and each movement has dates so I want to take those dates and that they are grouped in rationing to the months and that it can be similar to the link I put above. For example: The bank account is in a movement dated 07/02/2019 and 07/16/2019, so that account must show that it is in the month of July in the hearing.